# Step in proof of Cayley-Hamilton theorem in Steinberg's book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

I am reading "Representation Theory of Finite Groups - An Introductory Approach" by Benjamin Steinberg, and making exercise 2.9. I can unfortunately not find a solution anywhere. Most of the steps I have figured out, except step 4. The exercise is the following:

Exercise 2.9. This exercise sketches a proof of the Cayley–Hamilton Theorem
using a little bit of analysis.

1. Use Exercise 2.8 (prove that for every complex $n\times n $ matrix $A$ there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is upper triangular) to reduce to the case when A is an upper triangular matrix.
2. Prove the Cayley–Hamilton theorem for diagonalizable operators.
3. Identifying $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with $\mathbb{C}^{n^{2}}$
   , show that the mapping $Mn(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ given
   by $A \mapsto p_{A}(A)$ is continuous. (Hint: the coefficients of $p_{A}(x)$ are polynomials
   in the entries of $A$.)
4. Prove that every upper triangular matrix is a limit of matrices with distinct
   eigenvalues (and hence diagonalizable).
5. Deduce the Cayley–Hamilton theorem.

If anyone could help with this or give some kind of hint it would be greatly appreciated. I just don't understand how I'm supposed to come up with such a sequence. I was considering maybe it's possible to use proof by contradiction and generalized eigenvectors, is this of any use?

Comment: What did you begin to write and where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: what are the eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: @BrunoB , I believe they are on the diagonal? Maybe one can start with a diagonal matrix and add elements in the upper triangle?

Comment: @Tosca Leave the non-diagonal elements alone, just wiggle the diagonal entries a bit.

Comment: Oh i see yes, it should not be complicated this way. One can simply include different sums with 1/n etcetera. Thank you so much! @BrunoB

Comment: The order of the steps is a bit weird. (1) is needed to prove (4) and it isn't related to the other steps. I will prove (2) first, then use (1) to prove (4), then prove (3), and finally use (2),(4) and (3) to prove (5).

Comment: $(1)$ isn't used to prove $(4)$ but to prove $(5)$ once you've gotten $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ though. As for the order of the steps, it might not be the best for the redaction of the proof but I'd argue it's good for the presentation of the logic of the proof itself, to be honest, but that's just my humble opinion